# Is it possible to equate a function name to another function name?

Tags: c++

I am not sure whether the following is possible. Can someone give an equivalent for this requirement?

```
if(dimension==2)
  function = function2D();
else if(dimension==3)
  function = function3D();

for(....) {
  function();
}
```

Comment: C or C++ ? What you need is a function pointer

Comment: "I know the following is not possible." - it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, assuming two things:

1. Both `function2D()` and `function3D()` have the same signature and return type.
2. `function` is a function pointer, with the same return type and parameters as both `function2D` and `function3D`.

The technique you are exploring is very similar to the one used in constructing a [jump table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017/what-is-a-jump-table).  You have a function pointer, which you assign (and call through) at run-time based on run-time conditions.

Here is an example:

```
int function2D()
{
  // ...
}

int function3D()
{ 
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  int (*function)();  // Declaration of a pointer named 'function', which is a function pointer.  The pointer points to a function returning an 'int' and takes no parameters.

  // ...
  if(dimension==2)
    function = function2D;  // note no parens here.  We want the address of the function -- not to call the function
  else if(dimension==3)
    function = function3D;

  for (...)
  {
    function();
  }
}
```

Comment: Big upvote for relating this to a jump table. Brilliant explanation.

Comment: @H2CO3:  Thanks. :) Too bad I'm capped.

Answer (score 4):

You can use function pointers.

There's a [tutorial here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) but basically what you do is declare it like this:

```
void (*foo)(int);
```

where the function has one integer argument.

Then you call it like this:

```
void my_int_func(int x)
{
    printf( "%d\n", x );
}


int main()
{
    void (*foo)(int);
    foo = &my_int_func;

    /* call my_int_func (note that you do not need to write (*foo)(2) ) */
    foo( 2 );
    /* but if you want to, you may */
    (*foo)( 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

So as long as your functions have the same number and type of argument you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is also tagged C++, you can use `std::function` if you have access to `C++11`, or `std::tr1::function` if your compiler supports C++98/03 and TR1.

```
int function2d();
int function3D(); 

int main() {
    std::function<int (void)> f; // replace this with the signature you require.
    if (dimension == 2)
        f = function2D;
    else if (dimension == 3)
        f = function3D;
    int result = f(); // Call the function.
}
```

As mentioned in the other answers, make sure your functions have the same signature and all will be well.

If your compiler doesn't offer `std::function` or `std::tr1::function`, there's always the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since you choose C++

Here's with [*`std::function`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) example in C++11

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int function2D( void )
{
  // ...
}

int function3D( void ) 
{ 
  // ...
}

int main()
{

    std::function<int(void)> fun = function2D;

    fun();

}
```

Comment: Yes, `std::function` is probably the right thing to use in C++.