# C array with "[ ]) (char **)"

Tags: c, arrays, declaration

I found the following declaration in the [lsh](https://github.com/brenns10/lsh/blob/master/src/main.c) source:

```
int (*builtin_func[]) (char **) = {
  &lsh_cd,
  &lsh_help,
  &lsh_exit
};
```

I'm relatively new to C, but the `(*builtin_func[]) (char **)` looks very odd. What does it mean?

(I'm more interested in the declaration, not the purpose of the code.)

Comment: array of pointers to function returning `int` and taking pointer to pointer to `char` as argument

Comment: Paste the declaration into cdecl.org, it will translate it to English.

Comment: explanation from [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*builtin_func%5B%5D%29+%28char+**%29)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a jump table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017/what-is-a-jump-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> int (*builtin_func[]) (char **)

It means that the variable builtin_func is defined as

> Incomplete array of pointers to functions that take pointer to pointer to char and return integers.

Next,

> = { &lsh_cd, &lsh_help, &lsh_exit };

the list of initializers will complete the array , making it of 3 such pointers -- supposing that all 3 functions follow a similar signature.

Comment: The `&` on these function names are redundant too.

Comment: Compound literal? I don't see any compound literal in here.